# Running Minecraft Education Edition on Linux

Tags: wine, zorin, minecraft

I'm attempting to get some form of Minecraft Education Edition running on a Linux PC that I have, (Zorin OS 16.1 64-bit). After moving the install files from an existing Windows installation of Minecraft Edu to my Linux PC, I was able to get Minecraft running using Wine (6.0.3)!

[image: Minecraft Edu on Linux!]

Unfortunately, the ability to log in doesn't work because Wine doesn't have a suitable implementation for Windows.Networking.Connectivity/Authentication libraries.

```
0188:err:combase:RoGetActivationFactory Failed to find library for L"Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation"

0024:err:combase:RoGetActivationFactory Failed to find library for L"Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdSystemAuthenticator"
```

A version of wine-staging 5.19 seems to have support for the networking stuff [Winehq 5.19 staging notes](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2020-October/175412.html) but I wanted to know what other methods/workarounds the wine community might have before I get my hands dirty with installing and configuring older wine builds.

Thanks!

Comment: I was just about to recommend just to buy the Java edition, which runs perfectly fine natively on Linux. Depending on context and income, it would probably save your time (=money) and definitely a lot of headaches, but they now charge 30 USD. :o

Comment: Haha, true, but it's fun trying to get software to run on platforms it wasn't intended to.

Comment: Yes it is funny when "it wasn't intended to". Minecraft was developed in java, so it should run perfectly on java. If it is for education purposes I could help you. Also we can use docker to do it with one sentence.

Comment: Education Edition is based on Bedrock, which is a C++ program that uses Windows libraries. @JRichardsz

Comment: According to this https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/minecraft-bedrock-edition-on-linux/, bedrock is linux native.

Comment: I believe that uses an Android emulator to run the .apk version of MEE. Still, thanks for showing that article, it may come in handy.